Bold \textminus, \copyright, and so on
I have been curious about this for a long time, so I thought I'd ask here while it is on my mind.
The \textminus command does not seem to understand \textbf, though {\boldmath$-$} does. Conversely, the \textcopyright and $\copyright$ symbols both obey enclosing \textbf but $\copyright$ ignores \boldmath. An example:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\textbf{\boldmath + vs.\ $+$; - vs.\ -- vs.\ \textminus\ vs.\ $-$}

\textbf{+ vs.\ $+$; - vs.\ -- vs.\ \textminus\ vs.\ $-$}

+ vs.\ $+$; - vs.\ -- vs.\ \textminus\ vs.\ $-$

\textbf{\textcopyright\ vs.\ $\copyright$}

\textcopyright\ vs.\ $\copyright$ vs.\ {\boldmath$\copyright$}

This produces the following:

I obviously can choose one or the other depending on context, but I am curious what the underlying cause is. In the case of the math-mode minus, it may be that TeX is "faking" the bold symbol, but the fact that the bold plus in text mode works fine leads me to think this is not the whole story. This also occurs if other font-related packages are included (e.g., mathdesign).
Edit: By the way, the use case that always trips this is trying to write things like, "A grade of C\textminus\ is necessary to pass this class" in a syllabus.

\copyright just does \textcopyright, basically, switching to text fonts first, if necessary, and \boldmath doesn't affect the fonts used for text.

If you make a document with just \textminus \textbf{\textminus} it works fine for me.

In your sample document, \textbf{\textminus} in visibly darker than \textminus.

Pluses and minuses
The output is correct. \textminus is the bold minus sign within the scope of \textbf{}, but it is not the same bold minus sign as the one used in maths mode when the bold maths version is active. The text symbol is wider but thinner than the maths symbol, but visibly different from its non-bold counterpart.
\textminus uses, by default, symbols from the so-called 'text companion' encoding (TS1), an encoding which is arguably the cause of more headaches than all other font encodings put together.
In contrast, the subtraction symbol used in maths mode typically comes from fonts with the OMS encoding (something-beginning-with-O Mathematical Symbols).
Consider the following simplified illustration,

The first line shows \textminus in medium and bold extended.
The second line is entirely bold: it shows the bold plus in text mode, then the bold plus in maths mode, then the bold extended \textminus in text mode and, finally, the bold minus in maths mode.
The third line shows the same addition symbols as the second, but the subtraction symbols are both in text mode, contrasting the medium and bold extended versions.
The fourth line uses font specifications to directly contrast the bold extended \textminus and the bold version of the maths minus i.e. it is like the second line.
The fifth line compares the medium \textminus with the bold maths minus.
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[debugshow]{tracefnt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \textminus
  \textbf{\textminus}
  
  \textbf{%
    \boldmath +%
    $+$%
    \textminus
    $-$%
  }
  
  \textbf{\boldmath +%
    $+$%
  }%
  \textminus\textbf{%
    \textminus
  }
  
  \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char'53%
  \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char'53
  \fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char61
  \fontencoding{OMS}\fontfamily{cmsy}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char0%
  
  \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char'53%
  \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char'53
  \fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char61%
  \fontencoding{OMS}\fontfamily{cmsy}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\selectfont \char0
  
  \normalfont
\end{document}

Copyright
The \copyright case is straightforward as this simply uses the text mode \textcopyright, even in maths mode. Hence, \boldmath is imply irrelevant here and the series chosen is independent of that used for the surrounding mathematics.
Here's the default LaTeX definition of \copyright:
\copyright:
macro:->\protect \copyright


\copyright :
\long macro:->\ifmmode {\nfss@text {\textcopyright }}\else \textcopyright \fi

Clearly, therefore, the independence of \copyright's bold/non-bold appearance is what we'd expect.
Addendum
Bear in mind that these symbols are drawn from different fonts, in some cases designed by different people at different times in different places. Although the core Computer Modern fonts were designed by Knuth, symbols such as \textminus are later additions. Moreover, your distribution is probably/may not be using the fonts in their original form, but instead one of the later conversions to postscript type 1.
The thing to remember is that this is a feature (or un-feature) of the fonts used and not a constraint imposed by the way LaTeX selects fonts. So, if you prefer greater consistency, you can load a different font configuration. You could even just redefine \textminus to use the characters from cmsy and cmbsy, though this might result in even greater inconsistencies in sans or typewriter text, for example.

I figured it was something about font encoding. It just seems odd that \textminus inside \bfseries and \textbf look different than + inside the same.

@karlh remember that the symbol used for \textminus here is not in the original Computer Modern at all - it is coming from the text companion encoding, which is a lot later. there is no \textminus in plain.

See if this answer suits you.
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,amsbsy,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,textcomp,}

%uncomment and see
%\usepackage{fontspec}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    normal & \textbf{bm} & pmb\\
    \hline
    $3-3$ & $3\bm{-}3$ & $3\pmb{-}3$\\
    \hline
    $3\textminus3$ & $3\bm{\textminus}3$ & $3\pmb{\textminus}3$\\
    \hline
    $3+3$ & $3\bm{+}3$ & $3\pmb{+}3$\\
    \hline
    $\copyright$ & $\bm{\copyright}$ & $\pmb{\copyright}$\\
    \hline
    $\textcopyright & $\bm{\textcopyright}$ & $\pmb{\textcopyright}$\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}



Welcome! your answer has \textminus producing an equals sign. also, your source has 5 lines, but the output only appears to have 4. did you trim one off when cropping?
